# Delphi PCRE/regex implementations and stack overflow

Tags: regex, delphi, stack-overflow, pcre

I have found a case where e.g. 500 letters/digits with whitespace makes PCRE blow up when using \w in the regex. I have tried boh `TPerlRegEx` and Delphi XE2 pcre/obj implementations. Same for both.

I then tried calling

```
pcre_config(PCRE_CONFIG_MATCH_LIMIT, @vSysStrRegex_MatchLimit_Value);
```

But setting match limits does not seem to have any effect. The way I am using it is that I call it once for each thread. (Note: Others have set this to *get* not *set* such settings)

I really need the regex library to drop out of parsing instead of continuing until it overflows the stack. (It seems next to impossible to recover the thread/program from that.)

How do I prevent stack overflows in this situation? I can't control the content parsed or the regular expressions. Thus I am specificly looking for ways to avoid PCRE running into stack overflows through a setting or similar.

Solution by editing TPerlRegEx code:

```
function TPerlRegEx.Match(AStartOffset: Integer = 0): Boolean;
...
if FHints <> nil then // set by "study" call
  begin
    PPCREExtra(FHints)^.flags := PPCREExtra(FHints)^.flags or PCRE_EXTRA_MATCH_LIMIT_RECURSION;
    PPCREExtra(FHints)^.match_limit_recursion := 750 // 1000 too much in tests
  end
;
OffsetCount := pcre_exec(FPattern, FHints, ...)
```

Comment: I am asking if anyone has a solution to the problem and/or why pcre_config seems to be ignored?

Comment: This question is weaker for the absence of a reproducible test case

Comment: According to [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcre_config), `pcre_config` is for *reading* how the particular PCRE library was configured at compile time. It tells you which features the library supports, and to what extent. So *of course* it doesn't work to *set* a limit.

Comment: I must admit I am new to PCRE: I just saw http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt / LIMITING PCRE RESOURCE USAGE: **However, you can set a lower limit by adding, for example, --with-match-limit-recursion=10000 to the configure command. This value can  also  be  overridden at run time** is a quote from he help. I figured that pcre_config had to be the call to make changes runtime. Obviously I must have been wrong, but I tried using Google back and forth for hours for examples of changing match limit runtime. I guess I have failed. How do I change it runtime?

Comment: The documentation said it can over overridden at run time. You didn't misunderstand what "run time" means. You just didn't read the relevant part of the documentation. To find the relevant part, I searched the documentation for "recursion" until I found something that talked about setting it at run time.

Comment: This code seems to fail when using Delphi XE2 64bit (but works with Delphi XE2 32bit), specificly setting *PCRE_EXTRA_MATCH_LIMIT_RECURSION* flag. Can anyone else duplictae this problem? For reference see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041772/delphi-xe2-pcre-with-limit-recursion-fix-not-working-in-64bit-ideas (but this SO is the correct to discuss it further I believe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've cited [some PCRE documentation](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) that describes setting the recursion limit *at compile time* with the `--with-match-limit-recursion` configuration option. You can exercise that option if you build the PCRE library yourself. If you read elsewhere in that same document, you'll find a description of the `match_limit_recursion` field of the `pcre_extra` block passed to `pcre_exec`:

> The default value for `match_limit_recursion` can be  set  when  PCRE  is built;  the  default  default  is  the  same  value  as the default for `match_limit`. You can override the default by suppling `pcre_exec()`  with a   `pcre_extra`   block  in  which  `match_limit_recursion`  is  set,  and `PCRE_EXTRA_MATCH_LIMIT_RECURSION` is set in  the  `flags`  field.  If  the limit is exceeded, `pcre_exec()` returns `PCRE_ERROR_RECURSIONLIMIT`.

So, set the recursion limit to something lower than the default. The default is evidently even higher than your actual available stack space; if it were lower, then you'd *already* be getting the `PCRE_ERROR_RECURSIONLIMIT` error instead of an OS-raised stack-overflow exception.

How the Delphi-specific wrappers represent this setting, I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rob. I tried both Google and searching the PCRE.pas Delphi sources, but must have missed your solution. I will test it and report back! (And accept the answer. Upvoted it for now.)

Comment: It works. I set match_limit_recursion to 750 since 1000 was too much. (Now, I know I could increase stacksize of he threads as well, but, well, I prefer this solution!) I have accepted your answer :)

Comment: @Tom, for future references - perhaps you add the final solution to your question, how exactly did u overrode settings at runtime.

Comment: @Arioch No, that's the wrong place to add it. Add solutions in answers.

Comment: @David - but it was not HIS solution, and he'd not steal the thunder. Or you mean adding his own solution, but not approving it ? Then many readers would just bypass it.

Comment: @Arioch'The Answers go in answers, not in questions. So, yes, a new answer explaining the solution is fine. But not in the question. That's plain wrong.

Comment: Another option is to add the details to the existing answer. This *is* a wiki, remember.